# How do I utilize multiprocessing module in Python?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I'm trying to add an alarm sound to my timer program, however whenever the function for the sound gets called, the program times out, and you have to wait until the sound file finishes. I've tried using **asyncio** and right now I'm trying to use **multiprocessing** modules to resolve this issue, however I've kept on hitting my head against a brick wall.

Here is my code right now for the program

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import time
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play
import multiprocessing


duration = 500  # milliseconds
freq = 440  # Hz
sg.theme('DarkBrown4')
song = AudioSegment.from_mp3("alarm.mp3")
quiet_song = song - 40

def sound():
    play(quiet_song)



def main():
    centered_column = [[sg.T(('Set Time to Study'), font=('Consolas', 20))],
                       [sg.T((''), font=('Consolas', 20), key='countdown')],
                       [sg.B('Exit'),
                        sg.B('Start/Stop')],  # Buttons For Timer
                       [sg.B('Pomodoro'),
                        sg.B('Short Break'),
                        sg.B('Long Break')
                        ]]

    layout = [[sg.Text(key='-EXPAND-', font='ANY 1', pad=(0, 0))],  # the thing that expands from top
              [sg.Text('', pad=(0, 0), key='-EXPAND2-'),  # the thing that expands from left
               sg.Column(centered_column, vertical_alignment='center', justification='center', k='-C-')]]

    window = sg.Window('StudyWare Timer', layout, size=(400, 200), grab_anywhere=True, resizable=True, finalize=True)
    window['-C-'].expand(True, True, True)
    window['-EXPAND-'].expand(True, True, True)
    window['-EXPAND2-'].expand(True, False, True)

    active = False
    value = 0


    while True:
        event, values = window.Read(timeout=1000)
        # print(event, values)

        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
            break

        m, s = divmod(value, 60)
        timerx = "%02d:%02d" % (m, s)


        if event == 'Pomodoro':
            # active = not active
            value = 1
            window.Element('countdown').Update(value=timerx)

        if event == 'Short Break':
            # active = not active
            value = 300
            window.Element('countdown').Update(value=timerx)
        if event == 'Long Break':
            # active = not active
            value = 900
            window.Element('countdown').Update(value=timerx)
        if event == 'Start/Stop':
            active = not active

        if event == '__TIMEOUT__' and active:
            window.Element('countdown').Update(value=timerx)
            value -= 1
            if value == -1:
                active = not active

    window.refresh()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=main())
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=sound())
    p2.start()
    p.start()
    p2.join()
    p.join()
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! )))

Comment: Multiprocessing is a mess, I strongly advise you not to use it for that unless you have no other choice since it will make your program far more complex, bug prone and less flexible (not to mention the way to communicate with processes is quite limited in Python). Maybe multithreading is a better choice (though parallelism is not great in Python). In general using parallelism to solve concurrency issues add more problems than it solves.

Comment: I think for your case threads are good enough. Multiprocessing is for parallel computing using more than one CPU core.